# How do you show this isomorphism?

Tags: irrational-numbers

How do you show that $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$? What is a good starting point in showing this?

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb{R}$ has that cardinality? Do you know that $\mathbb{Q}$ has strictly smaller cardinality?

Comment: Isomorphism in what sense?

Comment: Iso in Sets, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

$|\mathbb{R}|>|\mathbb{Q}|$ $\implies$ $|\mathbb{R} \setminus\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{R}|=|2^{\mathbb{N}}|=|\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}|.$

Comment: What's the problem? Why downvote?

Comment: You didn't explain any step. Also, he asked for a starting point, not a solution.

Comment: But saying less would take so much longer ... :)

Comment: The amount of explanations needed strongly depends on the knowledge of the reader; if he doesn't know anything about cardinality then every answer is useless, if he knows a bunch of theorems in cardinality computation this is really clear. Moreover the problem is so easy that starting point=ending point.

Comment: You could at least note what theorems you use and whether they are proved with axiom of choice or not.

Comment: +1: consise answer, which still requires the questioner to think a bit.

Comment: I think that each step can be done in ZF: the first is additivity plus the fact that k+l=max{k,l}, the second is surely in ZF and the third uses already mentioned facts.